# JQuery Selectors: Select element with specific class and 'href' attribute using "contains:"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contains

I need to modify the following code (which works fine):

```
if ($("#cartable-items .cart-trigger[href='AC^ATZ^A10^4200']")) {

alert('Found it!');

}
```

To use the "contains:" selector like this:

```
if ($("#cartable-items .cart-trigger[href:contains('ATZ^A10')]")) {

alert('Found it!');

}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Jason

Comment: *Why* do you need to modify that to use the `:contains()` selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.. use the *= (Attribute contains word selector)  -  You can read more about the selectors here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$("#cartable-items .cart-trigger[href*='ATZ^A10']")
```

Comment: Thanks wirey. I'm getting the following error with this code though:

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Its OK I've worked it out. I was stupidly missing the extra parenthesis to handle my "if" statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This approach will also work. Here, the anchor tag has some class with `href` tag and also has the `data-open` attribute:

```js
$('.topnav-utility-item-link[href*="/VFLogonFormHopUp"][data-open]')
```